When or in which volume do Tatsuya's friends find out that he is Taurus Silver?
I would like to know if, in the current progress of the Mahouka Koukou light novel, Tatsuya's friends or inner circle have already found out that he is Taurus Silver. In the anime, they know he is an agent/soldier but not that he is Taurus Silver, and I'm really intrigued by that.
